# GTM visibility tag

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am creating a GA4 event in GTM. I have a web that features articles. Each article opens on an infinite page - after the user finishes reading the article there is infinite list of recomended articles. I am trying to create a tag, that will add an event in GA4 for 25 % scroll depth within the element, that has class .post-article.

So I set the GA4 event in GTM and chose the config tag for my GA4. I named the event and then I went to the trigger section. I created a visibility trigger. I named it and picked CSS selector. I put .post-article in the text field for the css selector. Then I chose once per page in the "When should the trigger fire" section. Then I wrote 25 in "minimum percentage of visibility". I saved and tested the tag in Google tag assistant and it does not fire. Could you please tell me what did I do wrong? My personal tip is that there is something wrong with the way how I wrote the CSS selector because everytime I tried to do a trigger based on a CSS selector, it did not work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If this setting doesn't work then yes you might need to upload a screenshot about the html and we can check the `CSS Selector`

Why I chose **Observer DOM changes** is because from your word.

It looks like the dom is showing after reading. The `infinite list`.

So the dom is not there at first place.

For this scenario and it should check the **Observer DOM changes** although it said something about performance possible issue.